# Question on a reduction to Roth's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

I'm looking at this paper: http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~bhowmik/enseignement/Mem_master/memoire_ramdin.pdf

On page 3, the author writes the following argument:

Let $B \subset \mathbb{Z}^+$ have positive upper density, so that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{|B \cap \{1,2,\cdots,n\}|}{n} = \delta > 0$. With $\varepsilon = \delta/2$, one can choose $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $\delta <  \frac{|B \cap \{1,2,\cdots,n\}|}{n} + \varepsilon$.

Perhaps I'm just too tired, but I can't see why this claim is true. Could someone explain this step?

Comment: It meant $ \delta <  \sup_{n \ge m}\frac{|B \cap \{1,2,\cdots,n\}|}{n} + \varepsilon$ ?

Answer (score 0):

By definition : $$\limsup u_n=\inf_n\left(\sup_{k\ge n} u_k\right)$$

So :$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{|B \cap \{1,2,\cdots,n\}|}{n} = \delta > 0\iff \inf_n\left(\sup_{k\ge n}  \frac{|B \cap \{1,2,\cdots,k\}|}{k}\right)= \delta > 0\\\Rightarrow\forall n,\sup_{k\ge n}  \frac{|B \cap \{1,2,\cdots,k\}|}{k}\geq\delta > 0\\\Rightarrow\forall n,\sup_{k\ge n}  \frac{|B \cap \{1,2,\cdots,k\}|}{k}>\frac\delta2\\\Rightarrow\forall n,\sup_{k\ge n}  \frac{|B \cap \{1,2,\cdots,k\}|}{k}+\frac\delta2>\frac\delta2+\frac\delta2\\\Rightarrow\forall n,\sup_{k\ge n}  \frac{|B \cap \{1,2,\cdots,k\}|}{k}+\epsilon>\delta$$